# List<string> checking null in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a function in C#.The code is given below:

```
public IList<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH> GetAdvSearchCandidate(List<string> strSkill, List<string> strRole, string strOrganization, string strPosition, string strLocation)
{

    //Code goes here
}
```

when I am calling the function sometimes strSkill or strRole become null.But how to check strRole/strSkill? I have tried strSkill!=null but it gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IList<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH> GetAdvSearchCandidate(List<string> strSkill, List<string> strRole, string strOrganization, string strPosition, string strLocation)
{
    if(strSkill == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("strSkill");
    }

    // do all other checks

    // your code
}
```

Null-checks are pretty much standard procedure.

**SideNote:** you may want to read a good book on C# coding standards. Apart from null checks it also explains variable and function naming. You code looks like an example of how to not do it.

Either as a book: [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) or as a MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: why can we apply if(strSkill !=null)?Please help.

Comment: @amitabha You need to show your code you used when you got the error and say exactly what error you got if you want any help with that. You made a mistake, we can not tell you what mistake you made unless you show us what you did.